# How to check for an exception based on date variable and service type variable

Tags: r

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck8EX.png)

Let's say for each IMEI number I want to check an exception case - if there are other services that have been logged post swapping of a product. How do I get the result in r something like this?
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAGy8.png)

Basically, there should not be any call logs created for the same IMEI after the swap

Edited: This is the structure I have, since it's a huge data I have created a sample of the same

```
structure(list(IMEI = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("123", 
"124", "165"), class = "factor"), `Service type` = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("in warranty", "repair", "swap"), class = 
"factor"), `accept time` = structure(c(1632172020, 1634922540, 
1629277800, 1631646180), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), `order id` = c("ID21", "ID24", "ID65", "ID70")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use `dput` to share your datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can group by `IMEI`, and filter where

1. `swap` exists as one of the service types for that IMEI, AND
2. it is not the last service type.

```
df %>% group_by(IMEI) %>% 
  filter(
    any(`Service type` == "swap"), 
    last(`Service type`,order_by = `accept time`)!="swap"
  )
```

Output:

```
   IMEI `Service type` `accept time`       `order id`
  <dbl> <chr>          <dttm>              <chr>     
1   123 in warranty    2021-09-20 21:07:00 ID21      
2   123 swap           2021-09-14 19:03:00 ID70
```

Input:

```
df = tibble(
  IMEI = c(123,124,165,123),
  `Service type` = c("in warranty", "repair", "in warranty", "swap"),
  `accept time` = c("20-09-2021 21:07","22-10-2021 17:09","18-08-2021 09:10","14-09-2021 19:03"),
  `order id` = c("ID21","ID24","ID65","ID70")
) %>% mutate(`accept time` = lubridate::as_datetime(`accept time`,format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
```

Comment: But the same code is giving me 0 result

Comment: you never provided us your data, using `dput(head(df))`, or something similar. Perhaps your data types are different.  Did you see that in my example data, IMEI is integer, Service type is character, order_id is character, and accept time is changed to date format? Does that match your data?

Comment: True, data types in my case are a bit different. I have added that now.

Comment: I got the desired result after sorting the accept time along with your code. Thank you. It helped me a lot.